# How do I manage Signing Certificates when working under another persons developer account

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, certificate

So I have a client who I’ve built this app for. The app had reached its MVP so we launched it and transferred the app to their developer account. Now I want to continue working on the app for them but I don’t have the proper certificate on my device to make changes to the project on the clients developer account. How do I go about getting the proper certificates set up so I can upload new app versions of the app to their App Store Connect account?

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions I can think of :

1. They can add your Apple developer account into their new developer account and give you the developer access (or admin access to have a bigger freedom). Therefore you will be able to recreate certificates for you in order to work on your project. (for me this is the best approach and it keep things clean). To do so, just ask one of the admin of the itunesconnect account on your client side, and he will add you as a Developer Manager in the account.
2. you can ask them to export their new certificates as a .p12 file (which contain the private and public keys) and their provisioning profile from their Mac OS key chain (the developer or team from your client that is handling the app nowadays if any). Then you will have no issue at all. (I do not recommend this one  and vouch for the first one even if second one seems easy). Also if tomorrow they changed it or revoke it will require to do again the same update..